# How to compile java code from a .net application?

Tags: c#, java, .net, compilation

I am creating a source code editor for Java using C# in .NET 4. I need to know how I can interact with the jre to compile the java code on my application editor interface from .net. I wish to display the user any errors on the code as well. Any ideas on how to accomplish this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can run `javac` just like any other application. I assume this is just an exercise given there are many free IDEs for Java already.

Comment: For a tighter integration with the Java world you may want to consider using iKVM.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the JRE is the *runtime*, and as such doesn't come with the compiler. You will require the [JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1637583.html) to compile.

I think the simplest solution is to spawn off an instance of [javac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) from within your .Net application. Perhaps a preferable solution (however) would be to write your app in Java itself, and you can then make use of the [Java compiler API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) directly within your app.

Comment: @Andrew - thanks for the update. I confess I didn't worry too much about the version, rather to illustrate the *presence* of such an API

Comment: Cool.  Got my up-vote even before the edit.  I wish Oracle would implement my [RFE for latest docs](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7090875). It would take only a few hours to set up, would quickly become the top hit in search engines, and save me a lot of editing time.. :(

Comment: You do not have to write anything in Java in order to get an access to any of the Java native APIs. There is a much better solution: you can call hell from heaven via iKVM.

Comment: @Andrew - that RFE is most worthwhile. Glad to see it's been accepted at least.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the most natural interoperability method is to run the Java code in a JVM, the .NET code in a CLR, and use a runtime bridge to manage the communications between them. In this scenario, the .NET code calls .NET classes and objects that act as proxies for the Java classes and objects. The proxies manage the communication; the calling .NET classes aren't even aware that they're ultimately calling Java classes. A runtime bridge provides interoperability for a wide variety of architectures, because the Java code and the .NET code can be on different machines, the Java code can run in a standalone JVM or in a Java EE application server, and the solution provides interoperability for any JDK version. As with bytecode translation solutions, you need only the Java bytecodes, not the source.

The code for this article uses JNBridgePro from JNBridge.

Comment: *"The code for this article uses JNBridgePro from JNBridge."*  Huh?  Was 'this article' supposed to be a link?  If so, a good reminder is that the 'page title' is generally better text to use for the link text.  Web page authors often put a lot of thought into the title.